# How to add external modules to clean architecture in Android

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I am developing a sample app, trying out the clean architecture approach. So, in the clean architecture you have three layers; Presentation, Domain and Data. So if i want to add a component that does does audio processing for example, would that become a layer on its own or would that belong to the data layer ??

Comment: I thought the latest pattern for Android architecture was called Model, View, Presenter.  I have never heard of the thing you referenced.

Comment: Well the MVP architecture is part of the presentation layer of the clean architecture. The idea of the clean architecture is to have separation of concerns. So, in the presentation layer would have all the views and their behaviors. The domain would have all the use cases of your project and finally the data layer would have your database and network connection.
checkout this link for detailed explanation. 
http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your preferred architecture model, audio processing sounds like Domain responsibility.  Recording audio isn't related to a view, but you might be *updating* a view as a result of incoming audio, such as a volume meter or visualization of the waveform.  You might also be dealing with model objects as a result of Audio data, such as saving audio clips, or the results of speech to text processing.